# Where Exactly Should I Place .GitIgnore File in Android Studio Project

Tags: git, gradle, android-studio

I have placed the following .gitignore file at the root of my Android Studio Project

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Windows clutter
Thumbs.db

# Intellij IDEA (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067)
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/datasources.xml
.idea/dataSources.ids
```

However the following .gradle contents keeps getting added to the source control.

```
 modified:   .gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
 modified:   .gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin
 modified:   .gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
 modified:   .gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
```

.gradle and its sub folders are marked to be ignored in the .gitignore however these keeps getting updated each time I so much as run the app in an Emulator. I do not remember dealing with these in Eclipse projects.

Are these .gradle files I showed above necessary to be version controlled, if not how can I modify my .gitignore to actually ignore them?

Comment: I've simple `.gradle` in my `.gitignore` file. It works.

Comment: Thanks, its still happening after changing .gradle/ to simple .gradle and I even tried .gradle/* and it still happens. Those files gets modified each time I ran the app.

Comment: No idea then :/ What comes to my head is that it may be OS specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the .gradle files are already in the git repository you need to clean them up first using `git rm -rf gradle/`.  Don't forget to commit your changes after using git rm.

Answer (score 2):

If you getting .gradle/X.XX/... poping up in your local changes tab then use

**`git rm -rf .gradle/`**  (NOTE THE DOT)

otherwise you will remove gradle folder which includes your wrapper folder.